# Cannot execute nested command on remote host over ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-runner

Im running the following command in my GitLab CI job:

```
ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} "docker restart $(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' | grep '^backend')"
```

The problem is that it returns me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 156: docker: command not found
"docker restart" requires at least 1 argument.
```

I know that `docker` does exist and works on the remote host, because I can log in to the host's shell and execute docker commands myself.

Based on my understanding the error seems two be two-fold - it tells me that "docker command is not found" and then tells me that "docker restart needs at least 1 argument".

So, I assume that the `docker` executable is not found for the nested command, which returns the "docker: command not found" error, and since that returns no names of containers, then `docker restart` fails as well.

I also tried replacing `docker` with `/usr/bin/docker` inside the nested command, but to no avail.

I know the ssh tunnel works correctly because just before that command, I execute the following two commands, which work fine:

```
ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} "docker pull my_registry/backend:${VERSION} "
ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --detach --remove-orphans"
```

So, I really believe the issue is that the `docker` executable isn't found for the inner command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quoted string will still allow local bash shell to expand the variables, command substitution,... inside the string.

This means that your command will execute `docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' | grep '^backend'` on the local machine, not on the remote machine as you intend.

```
ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} "docker restart $(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' | grep '^backend')"
```

You could try escaping it with:

```
ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} "docker restart \$(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' | grep '^backend')"
```

Or use single quotes. Here is an example:

```
ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} 'docker restart $(docker ps --format {{.Names}} | grep ^backend)'
```

More details you can find the the [bash(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#QUOTING) man page in the QUOTING section.

> ```
>    There are three quoting mechanisms: the escape character, single
>    quotes, and double quotes.
>
>    A non-quoted backslash (\) is the escape character.  It preserves
>    the literal value of the next character that follows, with the
>    exception of <newline>.  If a \<newline> pair appears, and the
>    backslash is not itself quoted, the \<newline> is treated as a
>    line continuation (that is, it is removed from the input stream
>    and effectively ignored).
>
>    Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value
>    of each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not
>    occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
>    Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value
>    of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `,
>    \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.  When the shell is
>    in posix mode, the ! has no special meaning within double quotes,
>    even when history expansion is enabled.  The characters $ and `
>    retain their special meaning within double quotes.  The backslash
>    retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the
>    following characters: $, `, ", \, or <newline>.  A double quote
>    may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a
>    backslash.  If enabled, history expansion will be performed
>    unless an !  appearing in double quotes is escaped using a
>    backslash.  The backslash preceding the !  is not removed.
> ```

Comment: Awesome answer, just one nitpick: the braces should not be escaped. If escaped the command will not be executed but used verbatim.

Comment: Woah, thanks for the awesome explanation!

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider. Fixed the escaping.